# Update the UI of the View Controller and then dismiss it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a view controller, that loads some an array. While everything is loading, I need to present another view controller (with the `UIProgressView`) and update it's UI (the progress property of a `UIProgressView`) and then dismiss and present first vc with downloaded data. I'm really struggling on it and I've tried delegation, but nothing worked for me.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"downloaded"]) {

        } else {
            NSLog(@"First time Launched");
            ProgressIndicatorViewController *progressVC = [ProgressIndicatorViewController new];
            progressVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
            [self syncContacts];
            [self presentViewController:progressVC animated:YES completion:nil];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"downloaded"];
            [progressVC release];
        }
    }
```

sync contacts method:

```
- (void)syncContacts
{
    NSLog(@"Sync data");
    NSMutableArray *allContacts = [ContactsOperations getAllContactsFromAddressBook];
    NSInteger allContactsCount = [allContacts count];
    if (allContactsCount > 0) {
        for (ContactData *contact in allContacts) {
            NSMutableArray *phoneNumbersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            NSString *nospacestring = nil;

            for (UserTelephone *tel in [contact.abonNumbers retain]) {
                NSArray *words = [tel.phoneNumber componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet :[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
                NSString *nospacestring = [words componentsJoinedByString:@""];
                [phoneNumbersArray addObject:nospacestring];
            }

            contact.abonNumbers = phoneNumbersArray;

            if (phoneNumbersArray != nil) {
                NSLog(@"NOT NULL PHONENUMBERS: %@", phoneNumbersArray);
            }

            NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:contact.abonNumbers, @"phoneNumbers", contact.contactName, @"fullName", [NSNumber numberWithBool:contact.isBlackList], @"blacklist", [NSNumber numberWithBool:contact.isIgnore], @"ignore", contact.status, @"status", nil];
            NSLog(@"dictionary: %@", dataDictionary);
            NSError *error;
            NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dataDictionary options:0 error:&error];
            NSLog(@"POST DATA IS : %@", postData);

            NSMutableURLRequest *newRequest = [self generateRequest:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@c/contacts%@%@", AVATATOR_ADDR, SESSION_PART, [[ServiceWorker sharedInstance] SessionID]] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] withHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [newRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
            [newRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            //__block NSMutableData *newData;
            [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:newRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                   completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
            {
                if (!connectionError) {
                    NSDictionary *allData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
                    NSLog(@"alldata from contacts: %@", allData);
                    //NSInteger errorCode = [[allData objectForKey:@"CommandRes"] integerValue];
                    //if (errorCode == 0) {
                        NSInteger remoteId = [[allData objectForKey:@"contactId"] integerValue];
                        contact.remoteId = remoteId;
                        NSLog(@"remote id is from parse content : %d", remoteId);
                        [[AvatatorDBManager getSharedDBManager]createContactWithContactData:contact];
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"error");
                }
            }];
            //Somewhere here I need to update the UI in another VC
            [phoneNumbersArray release];
            [dataDictionary release];
        }
    } else {
    }
}
```

generate request method:

```
- (NSMutableURLRequest *)generateRequest:(NSString *)urlString withHTTPMethod:(NSString *)httpMethod
{
    NSLog(@"url is :%@", urlString);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    [request setHTTPMethod:httpMethod];
    return request;
}
```

ProgressViewController is just an empty VC with the progress bar. No code yet.

Comment: So what is your problem? What were you expecting out of the code and what is it resulting in now? Specify that hopefully with screenshots.

Comment: Is the requirement to display a progress bar in a separate view controller or is the requirement to display a progress bar in the most efficient way possible? Are you simply assuming that it must be displayed in a separate view controller?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. For Bourne: The problem is I can't update the progress and dismiss the vc. In know it's just downloading data with no progress (I need to display progress while everything is downloading). To Murray Sagal: Yes, it is required to display it in a separate vc. If it was on the same vc, it wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Just fyi, commenters won't be alerted to any additional comments you make unless you begin the comment with their user name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view controller that will display the progress view expose a method like this...

```
- (void)updateProgress:(float)progress;
```

Its implementation will look like this...

```
- (void)updateProgress:(float)progress {
    [self.progressView setProgress:progress animated:YES];
}
```

On the main view controller you need to execute the long-running process on a background thread. Here's viewDidLoad for the main view controller. This example code uses a property for the progress view controller (you may not require this) and assumes your are in a navigation controller...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Create and push the progress view controller...
    self.pvc = [[ProgressViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.pvc animated:YES];

    // Your long-running process executes on a background thread...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    // Your long-running process goes here. Wherever required you would
    // call updateProgress but that needs to happen on the main queue...

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.pvc updateProgress:progress];
        });

        // At the end pop the progress view controller...
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but that was my first try :). The problem was that the task from the first vc was stopping - so nothing to update. I've solved it by running this task in ProgressVC, but many thanks for your answer, sir.

Comment: @PAcan I think it's probably that you need to execute the long running task on a background queue. I'll edit my answer to show that.